# How to extract exact 10 digit ISBN10 in google sheets formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have following data

```
ISBN: 9789380658797, 9380658796
```

How could I extract isbn10 only from the above string in google sheet using `REGEXEXTRACT` formula.

I have already tried below regex which is not working

```
1. (?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d) -> works in regexr.com but not in google sheets. Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)" is not a valid regular expression.

2. \d{10} -> return first 10 digit of isbn13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(?:^|\D)(\d{10})(?:\D|$)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uaGkew/1)

The point is that:

- RE2 regex library does not support lookarounds, so your attempts with `(?<!...)` and `(?!...)` are invalid
- You need to use a capturing group to extract that part only from the regex match, and in order not to match a non-digit or start/end of string, you need to use *non-capturing* groups, `(?:...)`, here, `(?:\D|^)` and `(?:\D|$)`.

[image]

Comment: Why not just use word boundary tokens?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld In case the pattern is glued to letters, or underscores on either side, there won't be any match. The digit boundaries are best in the general case. At any rate, `REGEXEXTRACT` always extracts the first match, so there is no headache about getting consecutive matches, and this approach is valid in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the advantages of your approach

Answer (score 2):

This also works in your case! I used an approach that used boundary `\b..\b` to isolate match strings. if it isn't working, please upload more data:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\b\d{10}\b")
```

[image]